# Entity framework update one to many association without have its navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

i have this two entities setup in this way:

Country -> Id, BrandId ecc. without navigation property
Brand -> Id, Description, ecc. with Countries navigation properties

in my webapi i receive a new brand (so without a Id until the save) and i need associate the relative country/countries to this brand. I know that if i have a Brand navigation property i can use it, but i want know if i can do the opposite. I need to find a way to add the BrandId on the Country entity in only 1 save. There is a way in EF to do this without adding the Brand navigation property on Country?

Comment: You mean that Brand entity has Countries nav property but Country does not have Brand nav property right ?

Comment: yes exactly. I know how to use navigation properties if the Country would have the Brand nav.. but without it there is a possibility to add a new brand associated to a existed country with only one save?

Comment: Have you tried to retrieve the Country, then add it to the Brand.Countries then add the new Brand to db ?

Comment: It will maybe create a duplicate of Country, I'm not sure about this, please let me know, I will update my comment if this happen

Comment: if i retrieve the country and add it to brand it throw a new exception because the country already exist (yes try to create a duplicate)

Comment: After the add and before the saveschanges, try to add db.Entry(your Country).State = EntityState.Unchanged. I'm on the pho e right now it might contains a typo

Comment: unfortunally the exception happen when i do the .Add